# What is the use of Expressroute gateway and VPN Gateway?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

We're setting up IPSEC Over Express route. I was wondering what's the need of VPN gateway and Express Route gateway?

My understanding is that with VPN gateway we can connect over the internet and establish a IPSec Tunnel. But why is it mandatory to create a VPN gateway (when the case is that I want to connect to site-to-site vpn over Express route).

Without creating a VPN gateway, we can't create VPN sites and links. I'm wondering why it's like that.

Expressroute gateway needs to be created in order to establish a connection to Express route circuits. But here also I don't understand the use of Gateway in general.

Is the gateway purpose is just to establish a connection between Azure cloud and Site-to-site or Azure cloud to Expressroute circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gateway is used to setup the connection to an ExpressRoute Circuit.
The Gateway can be used for both the purpose of establishing a connection to an ExpressRoute Circuit, and a S2S connection.
It's just a device. The way you configure it determines if it is a S2S over internet, or a S2S via expressroute.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways

> When you configure a virtual network gateway, you configure a setting that specifies the gateway type. The gateway type determines how the virtual network gateway will be used and the actions that the gateway takes. The gateway type 'Vpn' specifies that the type of virtual network gateway created is a 'VPN gateway'. This distinguishes it from an ExpressRoute gateway, which uses a different gateway type. A virtual network can have two virtual network gateways; one VPN gateway and one ExpressRoute gateway.

I hope that's a clear enough answer to your question.

Comment: Can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70110512/prevent-azure-expressroute-from-learning-routes-from-vpn-gateway