# Prevent Azure Expressroute from learning routes from VPN Gateway

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

How can I prevent Azure Expressroute from learning routes from VPN gateway? We're setting up a IPsec over Azure Expressroute. We want the Azure Expressroute just be a circuit. Right now Azure Expressroute is advertising the routes that's learned from VPN Gateway to the Edge routers.

Is there a way to prevent Azure Expressroute from learning routes from VPN gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Another tough question John!
I have never actually had to verify or look into this.

However, if I just go by what I know from the VPN Gateway: If it is route-based, you need to make routes in order for traffic to go where it needs to go.
So my guess is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#what-should-i-specify-as-my-address-prefixes-for-the-local-network-gateway-when-i-use-bgp

That page also mentions that when you route 0.0.0.0 to the Azure VPN Gateway all traffic goes egress to the 'on-premise' site. So if you would only route the traffic you want the rest of your VNET wouldn't be known to the S2S tunnel.

Comment: It seems VPN Gateway is advertising all the routes it has learned from azure (vnets) to Express route circuit. I want to prevent this because Express route then advertise all those extra routes to on-prem Edge router . Can this be prevented using `route-based VPN gateway`? Basically I want VPN Gateway to not advertise to Express route circuit.. Express route circuit should only be aware of the routes of On-Perm Edge router and MSEE. It should not know routes of vnets which VPN-Gateway has learned

Comment: okay, just the advertising and not the routing. I don't think you can limit that. I have not seen any functionality in the VPN Gateway for this. The BGP routes advertised from the on-prem, sure, but not the ones coming from the VNET. Might be good for you to ask one of your MS partners, Service Integrators, or simply by making a support ticket through the portal. The support ticket will likely get you a very definitive answer.